# transferOwnership function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Shouldn't following function

```
function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }
```

be written like this:

```
function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    owner = newOwner;
    OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
  }
```

To follow best practices of Check-Interact-Effect pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually Checks-Effects-Interactions, and there are no interactions here, so the order of those two statements doesn't matter.

An "interaction" in this context is a call to another contract.